# Displaying objects by categories in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm building an ecommerce app and I'd like to make a section that shows some featured items by category. I'm using three sliders that display those items; Each slider is a featured category and each item in the slider is a featured item. 
The problem is that I can't figure out how to assign the item to the proper slider. For example: I want to assign a JeansJacket to "Clothes and accesories" and display it. I tried this:

```
{% for cat in categories %}
    <h1>{{ cat.cat_name }}</h1>
     <!--(carousel code in between)-->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        {% for item in featured_items %}
            {% if item.Categoría in cat.cat_name %}
                {{ item }}
            {% endif %}
```

This is a simplified version of what I have, without the rest of the content. I just can't figure out how to iterate though the featured items and display them in the corresponding category.

Edit: This is in models.py:

```
class Categorías(models.Model):
    cat_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Destacado = models.BooleanField()
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('cat_name',)
        verbose_name = 'Categoría'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categorías'
    def __str__(self): 
        return self.cat_name

class publicaciones(models.Model):
    Título = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Descripción = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    Precio = models.FloatField()
    Fotos = models.ImageField()
    Categoría = models.ForeignKey(Categorías, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Promocionado = models.BooleanField()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Publicación'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Publicaciones'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Título
```

Comment: Can you share the item and category models and the queryset you use for the featured items?

Comment: There's the edit. What do you mean by the queryset for the items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`prefetch_related` and `Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) with a custom query to get all related articles for each category.

```
categories = Categorías.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch(
    'publicaciones_set',
    queryset=publicaciones.objects.filter(Promocionado=True),
    to_attr='featured_items'
))
```

Now you can loop over each category and then loop over this prefetch. You don't need to create a separate `featured_items` queryset

```
for category in categories:
    for featured_item in category.featured_items:
        ...
```

You can use apply this pattern to your template

Comment: I included that in the views but I still can't find the featured items when I loop through them, {%  for featured_item in category.featured_items %}

Comment: I added what you commented in views.py and passed it in the context to 'categories' : categories